# SQL Server dynamic sorting on multiple INT columns

Tags: sql-server, sorting, dynamic, sql-order-by

Using a stored procedure that uses parameters to determine the sorting, I can use this approach to sort on multiple string columns:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
            ORDER BY
            --  string order by
            CASE @SortDirection
                  WHEN 'ASC'  THEN
                    CASE @SortIndex
                      WHEN 1 THEN SKU
                      WHEN 2 THEN BrandName + ',' + ItemName 
                      WHEN 3 THEN ItemName
                    END            
                END ASC,
                CASE @SortDirection
                  WHEN 'DESC' THEN
                    CASE @SortIndex
                      WHEN 1 THEN SKU
                      WHEN 2 THEN BrandName + ',' + ItemName
                      WHEN 3 THEN ItemName
                    END
                END DESC
```

However if I want to order by more than 1 INT column, this approach doesn't work, presumably because I'm concatenating the comma as a string, and the case expression expects an INT datatype (explanation [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4162/conversion-failed-error-with-order-by-case-expression))

```
WHEN 5 THEN InStockLocal.Qty + ',' + InStockAll.Qty
```

This gives me the error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int
```

If I move the concatenation to the case expression that deals with strings, the ordering doesn't work as the values are no longer ints:

```
WHEN 5 THEN CAST(InStockLocal.Qty AS VARCHAR(10))  
       + ' ,' + CAST(AllStock.Qty AS VARCHAR(10))
```

How can I get round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think to get around this is to convert to a varchar, then make sure they all have the same amount of characters by adding leading zeros:

```
WHEN 5 THEN RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(InStockLocal.Qty AS VARCHAR(10)),10) 
+ RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(AllStock.Qty AS VARCHAR(10)),10)
```

I assumed 10 characters would be the max length because that's what you showed in your example.